# sqlboiler doesn't show any queries after debug mode

Tags: go, sqlboiler

I wrote `boil.DebugMode = true`, just after the db connection setting is.
However, when I write some select query by sqlboiler syntax, sqlboiler doesn't show any queries after debug mode.
Are there any reason I cant't see any queries in command line?

Comment: Can you share a related code snippet? Also, make sure that `boil` is imported with the proper version (sometimes VSCode skips the version when it handles auto-import)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code that works to print SQL logs into console

```golang
func Setup(dsn string) error {
    if len(dsn) == 0 {
        return errors.New("undefined DSN")
    }
    db, err := sql.Open("pgx", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
        return errors.New("DB server cannot be reached")
    }
    boil.SetDB(db)
    boil.DebugMode = true

    return nil
}
```